# Cannot extract model view properties of sheets

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have Revit file which has 3D view and 2D sheets. I can extract the model view properties of 3D model however metadata does not include 2D sheets' guid so that I cannot extract properties of 2D sheet.

Besides, manifest file has children that has a role of 2D and name of sheets however metadata doesnt include guids of 2D sheets. Has only 3D guid.

Why does it happen and how can we solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly:

- when you make the [GET {urn}/metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET) request, you only see the GUID of the single 3D view
- when you make the [GET {urn}/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) request, you see additional "viewables" with `role` set to `2d` but they don't have any GUID

Is that right? Usually, when the 2D sheets are not accessible through the Model Derivative endpoints, it means that they haven't been published in the original Revit document. But it's strange that they would still appear in the manifest itself.

Try checking the original Revit document, and see if the 2D sheets are published as usual, and if you're still having issues, I'd ask you to share the Revit document (confidentially - the file wouldn't be shared with anyone outside of Autodesk) with the support team via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`.